# How To Fix TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable In Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm Creating Whatsapp Script. I Have 8k Contacts I Want To Save Them All In Txt File. I'm ​Creating This Script in Selenium. But I'm Getting Error `TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable`

[image]

Here Is My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
input("Qr Code Done? : ")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

phnenumbers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('zoWT4')

for number in phnenumbers:
    print(number[0].text)
```

Thanks For Your Important Time And Help!

Comment: can you show us some HTML ? that class looks brittle. Also in which directory do you have `geckodriver.exe` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Okay, ```geckodriver.exe``` is on my project directory

Comment: The error is due to the fact that find_element_by_xpath is returning one element and not a list, thus TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object  try driver.find_element_by_class_name('zoWT4')

Comment: @Lakpa Thanks, How Can I Convert Phone Numbers Into Set?

Comment: just  do - list(phnenumbers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('zoWT4'))

Comment: @Lakpa Okay, Lemme Try This Code. Thanks For Your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`driver.find_elements_by_class_name()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_elements_by_class_Name#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) returns a list of elements, so you probably want

```
for number in phnenumbers:
    print(number.text)
```